# How can I get access to fields in a repeater and the main form from a function in the same Resource class (FilamentPHP)

Tags: filamentphp

I have defined an additional function performing some custom tasks in my resource's class. Inside it, I need to be able to refer to each field in each repeater row.

I see this very useful [post](https://github.com/filamentphp/filament/discussions/10399) but it applies to access within a closure. How do I get a hold of the fields from a function defined directly in the resource class?